# Trying to display a hidden div based on a select (dropdown) element

Tags: javascript, function

I have a select field for the country and I want to display a checkbox that is in a hidden div. This is the code I have on the site. Any reason why this wouldn't work?

```
<select id="country" name="field-010" required="" data-name="field-010" class="w-select" onchange="showDiv()">
  <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
</select>

<label id="gdpr" class="w-checkbox checkbox-field" style="display:none;">
  <div class="w-checkbox-input w-checkbox-input--inputType-custom checkbox"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="field-011" name="field-011" data-name="field-011" style="opacity:0;position:absolute;z-index:-1" data-di-id="#field-011"><span for="field-011" id="field-011" class="checkbox-label w-form-label">TEXT HERE</span>
</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showDiv(){
    if(country.value==United Kingdom){
      document.getElementById('gdpr').style.display = "block";
    } else{
      document.getElementById('gdpr').style.display = "none";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Correction:

> if(country.value=="United Kingdom")

Not:

> if(country.value==United Kingdom)

Use VSCode with a linter it helps

> https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @alex. This along with the other comment made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just one correction: United Kingdom should be in quotes

```js
function showDiv() {
  if (country.value === "United Kingdom") {
    document.getElementById('gdpr').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('gdpr').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="country" name="field-010" required="" data-name="field-010" class="w-select" onchange="showDiv()">
  <option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
  <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
</select>

<label id="gdpr" class="w-checkbox checkbox-field" style="display:none;">
    <div class="w-checkbox-input w-checkbox-input--inputType-custom checkbox"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="field-011" name="field-011" data-name="field-011" style="opacity:0;position:absolute;z-index:-1" data-di-id="#field-011"><span for="field-011" id="field-011" class="checkbox-label w-form-label">TEXT HERE</span>
    </label>
```

Comment: Thank you @gaganshera. This along with the other comment made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<label id="gdpr"....>` control to be a `<div>`, or add a `<div>` around the `<label>` and toggle the display style on that. You can't have the `<div>` inside the `<label>` element.